# Question about definition of graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, graded-rings

In the course of algebraic geometry I follow, the professor has introduced the notion of 'graded ring' to decompose polynomial ring $k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$ as follows:

$$k[x_0, \ldots, x_n] = \oplus_{d \geq 0}S_d$$

where he denoted $S_d$ the set of all homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$.

The definition of graded ring he gave confuses me a little bit. This was the definition:
A ring $S$ is graded if $S = \oplus_{d \geq 0}S_d$ for abelian groups $S_d$ such that $S_d \cdot S_e \subseteq S_{d+e}$.

The part which confuses me is the last condition: It makes sense to me if the $S_d$ are subgroups of $S$ (in that case I see elements of $S_d \cdot S_e$ as $x_dx_e$, with $x_d \in S_d$ and $x_e \in S_e$). But what if the $S_i$ are not subgroups and we have that $S$ is actually isomorphic to such a direct product? How is $S_d \cdot S_e$ defined in this case?

Comment: I think your confusion stems from the subtle difference between an [internal and external direct sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Internal_and_external_direct_sums).

Comment: @Quasicoherent that is probably true, I used to struggle with it during my commutative algebra class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have an isomorphism

$$ \varphi : S \to \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d $$

(note that, while $\oplus$ is more traditional than $\amalg$ here, I find it a poor choice of notation for reasons beyond the scope of this post)

Then, if the canonical insertions are notated as

$$ i_n : S_n \to \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d $$

then, for each $n$ we intend to identify the three groups:

- $S_n$
- $i_n(S_n) \subseteq \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d$
- $\varphi^{-1}(i_n(S_n)) \subseteq S $

Notation is intended to be flexible: we should be prepared to switch back and forth between any of these three groups on demand.

In particular, we should be prepared to multiply an element of $S_d$ with an element of $S_e$ by moving them both over to $S$.

So, $S_d \cdot S_e \subseteq S_{d+e}$ should be read as meaning exactly the same thing as

$$ \varphi^{-1}(i_d(S_d)) \cdot \varphi^{-1}(i_e(S_e)) \subseteq \varphi^{-1}(i_{d+e}(S_{d+e}))$$

---

For those allergic to this ambiguity, however, there is a rescue: you can always *strictify* such a scenario. Define the groups

$$S_d' = \varphi^{-1}(i_d(S_d)) \subseteq S$$

Then, the family of maps

$$ s_d = \varphi^{-1} \circ i_d : S_d \to S'_d $$

defines an isomorphism $s$ between any choice of coproduct

$$ s : \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d \to \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d'$$

and thus

$$ s \circ \varphi : S \to \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d' $$

is an isomorphism. In particular, this means $S$ itself is a coproduct of the $S_d'$, and so we can choose the coproduct so that

$$ S = \coprod_{d \geq 0} S_d' $$
$$ s \circ \varphi = 1_S$$

and so we've made $S$ into a coproduct of subgroups.

---

However, I strongly suggest getting used to working coherently with passing back and forth between the various identified objects. In my opinion, advances in category theory, homological algebra, and homotopical algebra *very strongly* suggest that the notion of equality is too strong; that one should only care about things up to isomorphism, or even just up to equivalence.

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about the insertionmaps.

Comment: Well, this is just an excellent answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I fully understand your question, but I may know where your confusion lies. The decomposition of a graded ring $S_{\bullet}=\oplus_{d\ge0}S_d$ is a decomposition of **abelian groups**, not of rings.

For instance, if $A,B$ are rings, then we'd usually define $A\oplus B$ to be the ring where multiplication is $(a,b)\cdot(a',b')=(aa',bb')$. This is *not* the multiplication we are talking about in $S_{\bullet}$.

In our case, the $S_i$ are always *additive subgroups*, but they are not going to be subrings in general (by definition, the only one closed under multiplication is $S_0$).

Look at the original example of $S_{\bullet}=k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$. Then $S_d$ is the abelian group generated by the monomials of degree $d$, so for instance $S_0=k$, $S_1=\langle x_0,\dots,x_n\rangle$, $S_2=\langle x_ix_j:1\le i,j\le n\rangle$, etc. (again, these are *abelian groups*, not rings/ideals). These are all additive subgroups of $S_{\bullet}$ but they are not closed under multiplication for $i>0$. But you can immediately see that $S_d\cdot S_e\subseteq S_{d+e}$.

Let me know if you still have some confusions. If you can be more precise with your questions, I can try to update my answer and help out any way I can.

Comment: My problem was if the $S_i$ were necesairely subgroups of $S$, perhaps not the best wording in my question :) but my explanation for the elements of $S_d \cdot S_e$ was correct then?

Comment: @Student Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

If $S:= \oplus S_i$, then each $S_i$ *is* a subgroup of $S$. For example, consider the group homomorphism $(x_1, \dots, ) \mapsto (x_1, \dots)$, whose image is $S_1$.

If $S \cong \prod S_d$ as an abelian group, then $S \neq \oplus S_d$, since there is no decomposition $(1,1,1, \dots)=( x_1, \dots) \in \oplus S_d$, since by definition there can only be finitely many nonzero terms. Hence, this would just not be a grading.

The multiplication condition is just making sure that the secondary operation (multiplication) also respects the grading structure of $S_d$ in a way compatible with "polynomial" considerations.

Comment: Okey, so the notation in the definition already implies that the $S_i$ are subgroups?

Comment: Well, this is somehow inherent in requiring that $\phi S \to \oplus S_d$ be an isomorphism (as in Hurkyl's post), since once we have that, we know that each $S_d$ is a subgroup of $\oplus S_d$ in a natural way.